# Can not use Foreign Key in migration if the referenced table listed after the table that use Foreign key in Laravel 6

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-6

Let's say I have 4 tables to migrate, its listed in these order in my program.

> 2019_11_11_021524_create_device_brands_table.php
>   2019_11_11_021820_create_device_types_table.php
>   2019_11_11_025212_create_transactions_ins_table.php
>   2019_11_11_150443_create_device_statuses_table.php

Then I reference all those 3 tables in `tranasctions_ins`

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('transactions_ins', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('DeviceType_id')->nullable();
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('DeviceBrand_id')->nullable();
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('DeviceStatus_id')->nullable();
            $table->timestamps();

            //Foreign Key
            $table->foreign('DeviceType_id')->references('id')->on('device_types');
            $table->foreign('DeviceBrand_id')->references('id')->on('device_brands');
            $table->foreign('DeviceStatus_id')->references('id')->on('device_statuses');
        });
    }
```

When I use `php artisan migrate` to migrate the tables, this error appear

> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table `inventory`
>   .`transactions_ins` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is
>   incorrectly formed") (SQL: alter table `transactions_ins` add
>   constraint `transactions_ins_devicestatus_id_foreign` foreign key
>   (`DeviceStatus_id`) references `device_statuses` (`id`))

But when i remove the `DeviceStatus_id` from `transactions_in` migration table the error dissapear, I know its happen because Laravel Doesn't know the `device_statuses` table doesn't exist, How do i solve this should i just delete the `transactions_in` migration table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

edit your migration file name 2019_11_11_150443_create_device_statuses_table.php.set a name that create before your transactions_ins_table

```
2019_11_11_023443_create_device_statuses_table.php
```

it means that your table is created before your transactions_ins_table .